# HTML5+JavaScript vs native app development 2015

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I know it is an old question, and there are tons of discussions online. But I found that almost all discussions happened in 2011 or 2012. And 2 reasons people favor native app over JavaScript:
1. access to camera, contacts, geo data and other device features,
2. user experience(faster response, multile-threaded when needed, etc)

Giving the development of JavaScript mobile frameworks, HTML5, and iOS and Android themselves in the last 2 years, has anyone switched their position? I am eager to hear from those who have used PhoneGap, JQuery mobile, etc. and had feedback from their end users.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth I've developed [some games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=BdR%20Games) in my spare time and I've tried phonegap/cordova and Cocoonjs. I think both are quite a hassle to work with and the end result is not so great.

I personally think html5/javascript development is a relatively easy and straight forward, but it cost me a significant amount of time and effort to set up the frameworks and fix framework specific issues.

For example Cordova couldn't even play simple sounds normally without using a plug-in, softkeyboard covering input boxes, weird canvas draw errors, canvas not loading at all on some devices. And CocoonJS is the fastest thing out there for canvas and action games, but it still runs much too slow on anything but a high-end quadcore device, which shuts out a large part of the potential users.

So in hindsight, I think going native would have cost an equal amount of time and effort with probably better results, so that would have been a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on JS-based mobile apps last 2 years and I can give you one disadvantage - debugging. It is always more natural to debug/trace native app then JS app on mobile. I always see JS debugging on mobile as more hacking then debugging...

Answer (score 0):

Wondering the same here... not only for games, but also for other app types.

I've used Android Java, LibGDX and CodenameOne. On server side, I've used Laravel and "raw PHP" - and dealing with JavaScript often makes me feel angry and frustrated.

At this point seems to me that HTML5 is a fantastic idea, but it would be better if the browsers support a more consistent scripting language (or if we had more consistency across platforms implementations of JavaScript).